# How to open a a dialog within the adapter? App keeps crashing once the onClickListener is run

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an application that's supposed to open a popup dialog when the user clicks on the item but crashes when clicked.
It started crashing as I added the **(this as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager** line.
Heres the code for the adapter pls help!!

```
class CategoryAdapter(var context: Context ,private val workoutList: ArrayList<CategoryModel?>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    inner class ViewHolder(private val itemBinding: WorkoutsListRowBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {


        fun bindItem(item: CategoryModel, position: Int) {
            itemBinding.workoutItem.text = item.name
            (this as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager

            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                itemBinding.workoutItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#072227"))
                itemBinding.workoutItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
            }
            else {
                itemBinding.workoutItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
                itemBinding.workoutItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
            }
            itemBinding.workoutItem.setOnClickListener{
                var dialog = CustomDialogFragment()

                dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "customDialog")

                Snackbar.make(itemView, "${item.name}", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemBinding = WorkoutsListRowBinding
            .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(itemBinding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = workoutList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItem(workoutList[position]!!, position)
    }

}
```

Here's the code for the fragment

```
class WorkoutListFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var categoryAdapter: CategoryAdapter
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentWorkoutListBinding
    var workoutList = ArrayList<CategoryModel?>()
    var workoutDAO: CategoryDAO = CategoryDaoArrayList()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentWorkoutListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root

        populateList()

        categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(requireActivity()!!.getApplicationContext()
            ,workoutList)

        binding.workoutListView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        binding.workoutListView.adapter = categoryAdapter

        return view
    }

    fun populateList() {
        workoutList = workoutDAO.getWorkouts()!!
    }
}
```

As well as the code for the custom dialog

```
class CustomDialogFragment: DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val rootView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_popup_dialogue, container, false)

        return rootView
    }
}
```

Error messages found in the logcat

```
2022-02-09 01:32:18.137 7210-7210/com.mobdeve.s11.mco2.deleon.coronel.grnd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mobdeve.s11.mco2.deleon.coronel.grnd, PID: 7210
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mobdeve.s11.mco2.deleon.coronel.grnd.adapters.CategoryAdapter$ViewHolder cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
        at com.mobdeve.s11.mco2.deleon.coronel.grnd.adapters.CategoryAdapter$ViewHolder.bindItem(CategoryAdapter.kt:26)
        at com.mobdeve.s11.mco2.deleon.coronel.grnd.adapters.CategoryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoryAdapter.kt:57)
        at com.mobdeve.s11.mco2.deleon.coronel.grnd.adapters.CategoryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoryAdapter.kt:20)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1775)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
2022-02-09 01:32:18.137 7210-7210/com.mobdeve.s11.mco2.deleon.coronel.grnd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:727)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6338)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6138)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
```

Comment: Paste the detail exception of the crash~

Comment: Hi sorry I'm still relatively new :( is this the crash details found within the logcat?

Comment: Yes you can find it in logcat.

Comment: LogCat always shows a stack trace of the exception that caused a crash. It tells you the line number that caused the crash and what you did wrong. Always include it when asking for debugging help because it makes it much easier to help.

Comment: Hello! I added the logcat details of the crash on the post just now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this as AppCompatActivity` doesn't make sense. Your adapter is not an activity, so you cannot cast your adapter as an activity and this will cause a ClassCastException crash.

If you need access to your fragment manager in this class, you need to add it as a property.

```
class CategoryAdapter(
    val context: Context, 
    private val workoutList: List<CategoryModel>, 
    private val fragmentManager: FragmentManager
): RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    //...

}
```

Then you can use it in this class freely. The Fragment that instantiates this class can pass the fragment manager to the constructor, like this:

```
categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(requireActivity(), workoutList, requireActivity().supportFragmentManager)
```

However, following the OOP concept of *separation of concerns*, I think a better strategy is to expose a callback for your Activity to use. A view adapter shouldn't have to know about specific fragments and fragment transactions, etc.

```
class CategoryAdapter(
    val context: Context, 
    private val workoutList: List<CategoryModel>, 
    private val onItemClicked: (CategoryModel)->Unit
): RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    //...


        fun bindItem(item: CategoryModel, position: Int) {
            itemBinding.workoutItem.text = item.name

            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                itemBinding.workoutItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#072227"))
                itemBinding.workoutItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
            }
            else {
                itemBinding.workoutItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
                itemBinding.workoutItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
            }
            itemBinding.workoutItem.setOnClickListener{
                onItemClicked(item)
            }

        }
    }

//...
```

and then in your Fragment that instantiates the adapter you can pass a listener that does the fragment transaction work, such as like this:

```
categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(requireActivity(), workoutList) { clickedItem ->
    val dialog = CustomDialogFragment()
    dialog.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "customDialog")
    Snackbar.make(itemView, "${item.name}", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Note I changed ArrayList to List. An ArrayList implies it will be mutated, but mutating a List that's being used by an adapter will cause bugs and crashes.

Comment: Hello can I ask what value I need to pass through the parameter when asked for a fragmentManager param? (Found within the fragment file)
categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(requireActivity()!!.getApplicationContext(),workoutList)

Comment: `categoryAdapter = Category(requireActivity(), workoutList, requireActivity().supportFragmentManager)`

Comment: It still results in an Unresolved reference: supportFragmentManager

Comment: Oops, see my edited comment.

Comment: I started getting a type mismatch in regards to the Category(requireActivity(), workoutList, requireActivity().supportFragmentManager)
This started happening after I added the private val onItemClicked: (CategoryModel)->Unit within the class CategoryAdapter params. Should I change the model unit to the FragmentManager model that I used before?

Comment: That's because a `FragmentManager` is not a `(CategoryModel)->Unit`. It's a completely different way to approach the problem. I recommend you avoid trying to learn programming through a ["cargo cult"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) strategy. Only write code if you know what it means, and if you don't, read up on the specific thing you're doing instead of guessing. You seem to have skipped over one of the basic concepts in OOP--what types are. You can't cast between incompatible types or pass something as a parameter if its type doesn't match.

Comment: I'll take that into mind, that's on me. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: I updated my answer to show what to do on the Fragment side in both cases, but I do recommend you read more about how types and type hierarchies work. The Kotlin documentation is somewhat lacking on this subject because it's written as if you already know some other OOP language. You might find some basic Java tutorials that talk about it, and you could read those to understand the concept without worrying about the different syntax.

Comment: And also there is no need for passing context if you need anything related context you have access to it in recylcerview itself